# Spring JPA annotation based web app

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

I am have JSON message as request object coming into Controller.
    I am trying to map the object to model class in the Controller class but unable to do so.
 Can anyone help me with the procedure.

```
package com.firm.trayportal.contoller;

import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.firm.trayportal.jparepository.trayMoveRepository;
import com.firm.trayportal.jparepository.LocationRepository;
import com.firm.trayportal.jparepository.StopoffRepository;
import com.firm.trayportal.model.trayMove;
import com.firm.trayportal.model.Location;
import com.firm.trayportal.model.Stopoff;
import com.firm.trayportal.service.trayMoveService;

@RestController
public class trayPortalquoteController {
/*  @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;*/

    private trayMove trayMove;
    private Location location;
    private Stopoff stopoff;

    // Service Layer

    private trayMoveService trayMoveService;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(trayPortalquoteController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/quote", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} )
    public ThumbsUp getActivetrayOrder(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody trayquoteRto rto) { 
        logger.debug("Start processing");
        if (rto != null) {
            logger.debug(String.format("Driver: %s/Load Number: %s/Stop %s",
                    rto.getDriver(), rto.getLn(), rto.getStops() != null
                            && rto.getStops().get(0) != null ? rto.getStops()
                            .get(0).getStop() : "?"));

            /*
             * Querying String insertSql =
             * "insert into tray_move (move_type, carrier_id, ln) values(?,?,?)"
             * ;
             * 
             * Object[] params = new Object[] {rto.getType(), rto.getDriver(),
             * rto.getLn()}; // define SQL types of the arguments int[] types =
             * new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
             */

            // execute insert query to insert the data
            // return number of row / rows processed by the executed query
            try {
                // int row = template.update(insertSql, params, types);
                trayMove trayMove = new trayMove();
                trayMove = savetrayInfo(rto);
            //  trayMoveService.populate(trayMove); // return type ?
                // trayMove row = trayMoveRepo.saveAndFlush(trayMove);

                // logger.debug(row + " row inserted.");
            } catch (Exception _ex) {
                logger.debug("Exception executing sql query:( Message: "
                        + _ex.getMessage());
                logger.debug("Exception executing sql query:( Message: "
                        + _ex.getStackTrace());
            }
        } else {
            logger.debug("quote RTO is NULL");
        }

        return new ThumbsUp();
    }

    private Stopoff saveStopOff(trayquoteRto rto) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private Location saveLocationInfo(trayquoteRto rto) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public trayMove savetrayInfo(trayquoteRto rto) {
        System.out.println("In savetrayInfo method");
        //trayMove.setMoveId(100005);       
        trayMove.setMoveType("IPU");
        System.out.println("In savetrayInfo MoveType");
        System.out.println("setMoveType");
        trayMove.setCarrierId(rto.getDriver());
        trayMove.setLn(rto.getLn());
        // TODO:rto.getName(); ??
        trayMove.setShippersno(rto.getShippersno());

        return trayMove;
    }

    public Location saveLocInfo(trayquoteRto rto) {
        // location.set
        // location.setAddress1(address1);
        return location;
    }

}

/*
 * create table tray_move ( move_type varchar(16), carrier_id varchar(32), ln
 * varchar(32) );
 */

class trayquoteRto {
    private String type;
    private String driver;
    private String ln;
    private String shippersno;
    private String oramplocation;
    private String orampadd1;
    private String orampadd2;
    private String orampphone;
    private String orampstate;
    private String orampzip;
    private String dramplocation;
    private String drampadd1;
    private String drampadd2;
    private String drampphone;
    private String drampstate;
    private String drampzip;

    private List<Stops> stops = new ArrayList<Stops>();

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public String getLn() {
        return ln;
    }

    public String getShippersno() {
        return shippersno;
    }

    public String getOramplocation() {
        return oramplocation;
    }

    public String getOrampadd1() {
        return orampadd1;
    }

    public String getOrampadd2() {
        return orampadd2;
    }

    public String getOrampphone() {
        return orampphone;
    }

    public String getOrampstate() {
        return orampstate;
    }

    public String getOrampzip() {
        return orampzip;
    }

    public String getDramplocation() {
        return dramplocation;
    }

    public String getDrampadd1() {
        return drampadd1;
    }

    public String getDrampadd2() {
        return drampadd2;
    }

    public String getDrampphone() {
        return drampphone;
    }

    public String getDrampstate() {
        return drampstate;
    }

    public String getDrampzip() {
        return drampzip;
    }

    public List<Stops> getStops() {
        return stops;
    }

}

class Stops {
    String name;
    String add1;
    String add2;
    String city;
    String ext;
    String phone;
    String st;
    String zip;
    Integer stop;
    Date apptment1;
    Date apptment2;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAdd1() {
        return add1;
    }

    public String getAdd2() {
        return add2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getExt() {
        return ext;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public Date getApptment1() {
        return apptment1;
    }

    public Date getApptment2() {
        return apptment2;
    }

    public Integer getStop() {
        return stop;
    }
}

class ThumbsUp {
    private String message = "success";

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

@Service
@Repository
public class trayMoveService {

    @Autowired
    private trayMoveRepository trayMoveRepo;


    @Qualifier("trayMove")
    public void populate(trayMove dm) {
        trayMoveRepo.saveAndFlush(dm);
    }

}

@Transactional
public interface trayMoveRepository extends JpaRepository<trayMove, Integer>{

}
```

The setter method doesnt work. I think m missing some annotations. Can someone direct me to the tutorial please ?
        The application is Spring JPA(EclipseLink) annotation based.

Comment: What do you that it doesn't work?

Comment: MoveModelClass model object is not being populated :-/

Comment: but I am doing is take values from RTO that is incoming Json object and populate the model class

Comment: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter  ??

Comment: If you could please include the entire code, and also a more thorough explanation of the problem.

Comment: added the controller file. I am here trying to populate the trayMove model class

Comment: Separate every class in it's different file, class names have to be with capital letter.
The problem most likely is due to the fact that you have not initialized the class model trayMove.
If you want to identify the problem and have a clearer view please separate the code into different files, and clean anything you don't use.

Comment: I jus did a quick change of the names didnt realize the lower case.

Comment: but anyways how I do the mapping for json to model class ?

Comment: If the rto object in the controller mapping is populated 
Here `public ThumbsUp getActivetrayOrder(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody trayquoteRto rto)` the there should't be a problem setting the informatin in trayMove. Try to delete the line
`private trayMove trayMove;` and create a new trayMove object in the method savetrayInfo

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation.         System.out.println("In savetrayInfo method");
        //trayMove.setMoveId(100005);       
        trayMove.setMoveType("IPU");
        System.out.println("In savetrayInfo MoveType");. It doesnt print this line"In savetrayInfo MoveType". setMoveType gives a  null for the attribute of the model object

Comment: As i told you, trayMove is not initilized and so a NPE is thrown when you try to call the method trayMove.setMoveId(*). Create a trayMove object in the method and return that object.

Comment: oops sorry. gotcha. let me try that .

Comment: ok .but now it should go to Service layer and from to repo and thereby insert into db table and I dont see that happening. let me past that code too

Comment: I'm assuming you use Spring Data JPA.

Comment: @NicuReut: Yes Spring Data JPA .

Comment: You have to have a datasource configured, and the entity to be annotated using JPA annotations. Please follow the instructions from spring site.
Here you have everything you need : [example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa.html). 
You need to configure the datasource, create the entity  (or use annotations for an existing entity) and create the repository by extending the JPARepository

Comment: I have those too in JPA config file .

Comment: Other than configuration, do you see anything wrong in the any of the layers ?

Comment: annotations for existing entity , I have only these : @Entity
@Table(name="tray_move")
@NamedQuery(name="trayMove.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM trayMove d")
public class trayMove implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Comment: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

Add this so that the primary key is created

Comment: Also make sure that you have enabled the JPA repositories.
And trayMoveService is not a repository, so you can get rid of the @Repository annotation

Comment: yes primary key is there. sorry i didnt paste the whole class. and thank you for helping me out :). Do you find anything else wrong in the classes ?

Comment: The only thing that i can think about is the fact that you are using Spring generated repositories (as you can see you only create an interface), so that you need to enable JPA repositories either in the JAVA config class or in XML config.
If that does't work than ask a new question, but make sure to include the code more clearly and the stacktrace of the exception if one is thrown.

Comment: Yes I enabled the repo in Java Config. Will check whats wrong. WIll surely post code more clearly next time. Thanks a ton again ! :)

Comment: @NicuReut: Eureka . it worked :) . Will implement the same for rest of the model classes. Also can you suggest me some tutorials to begin from basics on how to understand and work on these please ?

Comment: All that i can suggest is the book Thinking in Java for Java learning, and also if you want to learn Spring you can read Spring in Action (you have there all the important parts of spring, including Spring Data and Spring MVC).
Glad that i could help you.